# Angular2 Karma Testing with Underscore library

Tags: angular, underscore.js, karma-jasmine

I have a bunch of karma tests setup and working fine with Karma, but I have tried to add a new one that is testing a component that has underscore in it, but when the Karma test runs I get an error 404: /base/underscore and I not sure why.  I have put the underscore library into the files array, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here is the component that is being tested.  You can see that it is importint * as _ from 'underscore' at the top.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import * as _ from 'underscore';

import { PlanPeriodService, IPlanPeriodService } from '../../planPeriod/planPeriod.service';
import { PlanPeriod } from '../../planperiod/planPeriod.model';

import { PlanningBrokerService, IPlanningBrokerService } from '../../planningBroker/planningBroker.service';
import { PlanningBroker } from '../../planningBroker/planningBroker.model';

import { PlanningCustomerService, IPlanningCustomerService } from '../../planningCustomer/planningCustomer.service';
import { PlanningCustomer } from '../../planningCustomer/planningCustomer.model';

import { ShipToService, IShipToService } from '../../shipTo/shipTo.service';
import { ShipTo } from '../../shipTo/shipTo.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'chargeTo',
    templateUrl: './chargeTo.component.html',
    providers: [PlanPeriodService, PlanningBrokerService, PlanningCustomerService, ShipToService]
})
export class ChargeToComponent implements OnInit {

    private tradeSystemId: number;
    @Input() get TradeSystemId(): number {
        return this.tradeSystemId;
    }
    set TradeSystemId(value: number) {
        this.tradeSystemId = value;
        this.loadPlanPeriods();
        this.loadPlanningBrokers();
    }

    private planPeriodId: number;
    @Input() get PlanPeriodId(): number {
        return this.planPeriodId;
    }
    set PlanPeriodId(value: number) {
        this.planPeriodId = value;

        const item = _.find(this.PlanPeriods, (pp: PlanPeriod) => {
            return pp.Id === value;
        });
        if (item) this.PlanPeriod = item.Description;
    }

    private planPeriodIds: number[];
    @Input() get PlanPeriodIds(): number[] {
        return this.planPeriodIds;
    }
    set PlanPeriodIds(value: number[]) {
        this.planPeriodIds = value;

        const items = _.filter(this.PlanPeriods, (pp: PlanPeriod) => {
            var found = _.find(value, (n: number) => {
                return n === pp.Id;
            });
            return found !== undefined;
        });

        if (items.length === 0) {
            this.PlanPeriod = undefined;
        }
        else if (items.length === 1) {
            this.PlanPeriod = items[0].Description;
        } else {
            this.PlanPeriod = 'Multiple Periods';
        }
    }

    allowMultiplePlanPeriods: boolean;
    @Input() get AllowMultiplePlanPeriods(): boolean {
        return this.allowMultiplePlanPeriods;
    }
    set AllowMultiplePlanPeriods(value: boolean) {
        this.allowMultiplePlanPeriods = value;
        if (value) {
            this.PlanPeriodId = undefined;
            this.PlanPeriodIds = [];
        } else {
            this.PlanPeriodId = undefined;
            this.PlanPeriodIds = undefined;
        }
    }

    private planningBrokerId: number;
    @Input() get PlanningBrokerId(): number {
        return this.planningBrokerId;
    }
    set PlanningBrokerId(value: number) {
        this.planningBrokerId = value;
        this.loadPlanningCustomers();

        const item = _.find(this.PlanningBrokers, (pb: PlanningBroker) => {
            return pb.Id === value;
        });
        if (item) this.PlanningBroker = item.Name;
    }

    private planningCustomerId: number;
    @Input() get PlanningCustomerId(): number {
        return this.planningCustomerId;
    }
    set PlanningCustomerId(value: number) {
        this.planningCustomerId = value;
        this.loadPlanningCustomerCompany();

        const item = _.find(this.PlanningCustomers, (pc: PlanningCustomer) => {
            return pc.Id === value;
        });
        if (item) this.PlanningCustomer = item.Name;
    }

    @Input() PlanPeriod: string;
    @Input() PlanningBroker: string;
    @Input() PlanningCustomer: string;

    Company: number;
    PlanPeriods: PlanPeriod[];
    PlanningBrokers: PlanningBroker[];
    PlanningCustomers: PlanningCustomer[];

    loadPlanPeriods(): void {
        this.PlanPeriods = [];

        this.planPeriodService.getByTradeSystem(this.TradeSystemId)
            .subscribe((results: PlanPeriod[]) => this.PlanPeriods = results,
            error => console.error(error));
    }

    loadPlanningBrokers(): void {
        this.PlanningBrokers = [];

        this.planningBrokerService.getByTradeSystem(this.TradeSystemId, undefined)
            .subscribe((results: PlanningBroker[]) => this.PlanningBrokers = results,
            error => console.error(error));
    }

    loadPlanningCustomers(): void {
        this.PlanningCustomers = [];

        this.planningCustomerService.getByPlanningBroker(this.PlanningBrokerId, this.TradeSystemId)
            .subscribe((results: PlanningCustomer[]) => this.PlanningCustomers = results,
            error => console.error(error));
    }

    loadPlanningCustomerCompany(): void {
        this.Company = undefined;

        this.shipToService.getById(this.planningCustomerId)
            .subscribe((result: ShipTo) => this.Company = result.Company,
            error => console.error(error));
    }

    constructor(private readonly planPeriodService: IPlanPeriodService, private readonly planningBrokerService: IPlanningBrokerService,
        private readonly planningCustomerService: IPlanningCustomerService, private readonly shipToService: IShipToService) { }

    ngOnInit(): any {
        this.PlanPeriods = [];
    }

}
```

Here is the karma.conf.js file.  You can see in the middle of this file array that underscore is listed there.

```
module.exports = function (config) {

        var appBase = 'app/';       // transpiled app JS and map files
        var appSrcBase = 'app/';       // app source TS files
        var appAssets = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

        // Testing helpers (optional) are conventionally in a folder called `testing`
        var testingBase = 'testing/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
        var testingSrcBase = 'testing/'; // test source TS files

        config.set({
            basePath: '',
            frameworks: ['jasmine'],

            plugins: [
                require('karma-jasmine'),
                require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
                require('karma-htmlfile-reporter')
            ],

            client: {
                builtPaths: [appBase, testingBase], // add more spec base paths as needed
                clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
            },

            customLaunchers: {
                // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
                // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
                Chrome_travis_ci: {
                    base: 'Chrome',
                    flags: ['--no-sandbox']
                }
            },

            files: [
                // System.js for module loading
                'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

                // Polyfills
                'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',

                // zone.js
                'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
                'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
                'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
                'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
                'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
                'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
                'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

                //underscore
                { pattern: 'node_modules/underscore/underscore.js', included: true, watched: false },

                // RxJs
                { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
                { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

                // Paths loaded via module imports:
                // Angular itself
                { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
                { pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },

                { pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false },
                { pattern: 'systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false },

                'karma-test-shim.js', // optionally extend SystemJS mapping e.g., with barrels

                // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
                { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
                { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },

                // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
                // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
                { pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true },
                { pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true },

                // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
                { pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
                { pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
                { pattern: testingSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
                { pattern: testingBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false }
            ],

            // Proxied base paths for loading assets
            proxies: {
                // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
                "/app/": appAssets
            },

            exclude: [],
            preprocessors: {},
            reporters: ['progress'],

            port: 9876,
            colors: true,
            logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
            autoWatch: true,
            browsers: ['Chrome'],
            singleRun: false
        });
    }
```

When I start the tests with Karma I get and error

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/underscore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add to the map array in the karma-test-shim.js file.  It was successfully adding it into Karma, but then when it hit the import * as _ from 'underscore'; line that was changed into require('underscore'), which it couldn't find something just called underscore, so then I had to map underscore to the JS path.  Which is what I have done below.  The only difference is below I started using lodash instead of underscore, but same principal.

```
System.config({
    baseURL: 'base',
    // Extend usual application package list with test folder
    packages: { 'testing': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' } },

    // Assume npm: is set in `paths` in systemjs.config
    // Map the angular testing umd bundles
    map: {
        '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms/testing': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms-testing.umd.js',
        'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.min.js'
    },
});
```